# automate filling in web forms

Tags: python, forms, web-crawler

There is a text box (ID) on the website and I want to put 10,000 data in it. After placing each data in this text box, results are displayed in other text boxes according to the ID.

Textbox ID :

```
<input class="form-control ltr left text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-regex="It is 10 numbers" data-val-regex-pattern="^[0-9]{10}$" data-val-required="*required" id="NId" maxlength="10" name="NId" onblur="LoadInfo()" type="text" value="">
```

Textobx Name (fill after enter the ID in text box) :

```
<form action="/Employees/Manager/SavePerson" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="onpostcreatebegin" data-ajax-complete="onpostcreatecomplete" data-ajax-loading="#ajaxloading" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#result" id="form0" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="asdxBadsP7CpS53654as6dadH3865asdadKhjasdad">        <input type="hidden" name="empId" id="empid" value="0">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-regex="It is 10 numbers" data-val-regex-pattern="^[0-9]{10}$" data-val-required="*required" id="NId" name="NId" type="hidden" value="1234567890">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PersonId must be a number." data-val-required="The PersonId field is required." id="PersonId" name="PersonId" type="hidden" value="254102232">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The GuidId field is required." id="GuidId" name="GuidId" type="hidden" value="665xs6asd-cxc2-wq56-8888-30654998b166">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-regex="enter the name." data-val-regex-pattern="^[\u0600-\u06ff\s]+$|[\u0750-\u077f\s]+$|[\ufb50-\ufc3f\s]+$|[\ufe70-\ufefc\s]+$|[\u06cc\s]+$|[\u067e\s]+$|[\u06af\s]$|[\u0691\s]+$|^$" data-val-required="*required" id="Firstname" name="Firstname" type="text" value="jack">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Firstname" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

The page will not reload after entering the value in the text box ID. Shows the value on that page. What solution do you suggest? I do not know which method to consider that is the most optimal method. Can you introduce the most optimal and practical method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how complex the task is, you can use either [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) (Selenium is a script-controlled Browser) with [Firefox](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) WebDriver, for example.

It is of course also possible to use the [request methods GET and POST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) as a method with more work but much higher performance.